# How to extract stats data from statannotations package?

Tags: python, statistics

How do I extract stat values and p-values from the analysis conducted in [statannotations](https://github.com/trevismd/statannotations)?

This is my example code:

```py
args = dict(x="disease_state", y=gene_of_interest, order=['Normal', 'Tumour'])

g = sns.catplot(col="cohort", kind="box", height=4, col_wrap = 4, aspect=.7, sharey=False, data=paired, **args, color='white')
g.map(sns.stripplot, args["x"], args["y"], order=args["order"], palette=sns.color_palette(), dodge=True)

pairs=[("Tumour", "Normal")]

for name, ax in g.axes_dict.items():
# subset the table to generate stats
        annot = Annotator(ax, pairs, **args, data=paired.loc[paired['cohort']==name,:]) 
        annot.configure(test='Wilcoxon', text_format='simple', comparisons_correction="BH", verbose=2, loc='inside')
        annot.apply_test().annotate()
```

I think I need to use the [stats module](https://statannotations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/statannotations.stats.html) but I'm unsure how.

Comment: try "from statannotations import stats"? Not certain if it will work but that is how other modules are typically stored and retrieved.

Comment: Yes just not sure how to extract the results from the statannotations.stats.StatResult.StatResult object and move them into a dataframe

Answer (score 1):

According to the example in their GitHub page https://github.com/trevismd/statannotations/blob/master/usage/example.ipynb, "The annotate method returns the tuple ax, annotations, where annotations is a list of Annotation objects. The data attribute of an Annotation is a StatResult object, which containing both the original data of the groups (boxes for boxplots), and the statistical test results (p-value, etc)."

In your example,

> _, test_results = annot.annotate()

should give you the stat results. For the specific comparison tests you can use a for loop as in their example:

> for res in test_results:
> print(res.data)

From here on saving it as any format you need it is straightforward.

Comment: This is correct. Maybe this will help guiding @nathan-tear: 1. replace `annot.apply_test().annotate()` with `_, test_results = annot.apply_test().annotate()`; 2 . use `stat_results = [(result.data.stat_value, result.data.pvalue) for result in test_results]` to have a list of `(stat_value, pvalue)` for your pairs. @teodoro, feel free to use in answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the statistical values associated with your annotations by using :

```
annot.data.stat_value
```

The same works with the P-value.